# How to use $(this) inside onSelect method of datepicker ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to get the value of a hidden input when a date in my date picker is selected so I'm using the `onSelect` method then running `$(this).find('.js-hidden-date').val();` but this returns `undefined` but if I just run `$('.js-hidden-date').val()` I get the value I require. I'm guessing this has something to do with context but not sure how to resolve this?

**JS**

```
$('.js-date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd M yy',
    altFormat: 'yy, m, dd',
    altField: '.js-date-hidden',
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    beforeShowDay: available,
    onSelect: function() {
        console.info('4) Trigger event date:selected', $(this).find('.js-date-hidden').val());
    }
});
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/yXMKC/1602/

Comment: This is like the absolutely most basic part of Jquery. Look up the documentation on selectors. If you don't understand the difference between `$(this).find()` and `$(".className")`, your code isn't gonna do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `find`, it looks for the children, while `.js-hidden-date` is a sibling, you can use `next()` for this:

```
$(this).next()
```

If in the final code the hidden field it's not a direct sibling you can also:

```
$(this).nextUntil('.js-hidden-date').next()
```

Answer (score 0):

At that point, this is the original input. Your markup shows the input you are looking for as a siblings, not a child. the method .find() will look in the children. You should try siblings(), something like this:

```
$(this).siblings('.js-date-hidden').val()
```

Keep in mind that if you put more than one date pickers at the same level, siblings() will return all instance of '.js-date-hidden' that are on the same level.